# Ошибки сборщика "cannot open file ...lib"

Tags: windows, c++, visual-c++

Такая ситуация: раньше я работал на VS08, но сейчас пришлось по делу установить 10 студию, сначала были проблемы с библиотеками, подгружаемыми в проекте, но потом эти проблемы исчезли. Сейчас у меня другие проблемы, а именно при запуске одного проекта в режиме релиз он пишет ошибку:

> `1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib'`

(при запуске в режиме дебаг все проходит нормально), а при запуске другого проекта в режиме дебаг он пишет

> `1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msvcprtd.lib'`

(запуск в релиз проходит успешно). Как решить проблему и с чем это связано?

Answer (score 1):

Это может быть связано с опциями проекта и опциями Visual Studio, а именно: в списке подключаемых библиотек нет тех, что указаны в сообщениях об ошибках либо Visual Studio не может их найти. Чтобы исправить, сделать следующее - зайти в свойства проекта и там для варианта релиз и дебаг явно прописать недостающие библиотеки в список линкуемых библиотек.

Ну, и иногда подобные проблемы возникают, если линкуется библиотека с несовместимы рантаймом.

Comment: Все библиотеки прописаны, и физически находятся в системе.
А можно подробней про "линкуется библиотека с несовместимы рантаймом"

Comment: Есть готовая библиотека something.lib, которая собиралась на предыдущей версии MSVC, и, например, libc включена в нее. Исходников к ней нет. Если ее сейчас начать линковать к проекту, который потребует более поздней версии libc, то вполне может возникнуть конфликт версий. Обычно из этого положения выходят, выбирая опцию "Библиотека времени выполнения - многопоточная DLL", хотя может и не помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Только что возникла эта ошибка. Для тех кто будет гуглить и наткнется на эту тему напишу, что эта ошибка также может возникать из-за настройки путей для выходных и obj-файлов для одинаковыми для двух проектов в одном sulution. Перед компиляцией проекта очищаются его директории для выходных и obj-файлов.

Answer (score 0):

В Qt Creator такие ошибки бывают, если указана в настройках проекта "теневая сборка". Отключаешь её - ошибка исчезает.

В данном случае основываюсь только на опыт. У меня  такие ошибки появлялись, когда я забывал отключить "теневую сборку". Хотя саму первопричину появления ошибки я не знаю, как и не знаю сути "теневой сборки". Просто кому-то может помочь и такая информация.

Answer (score -1):

Просто поменяй DEBUG на RELEASE